# How do i query a database that stores times in utc, with ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, timezone, mongoid

I am in the Central timezone (`ENV['TZ'] = America/Chicago`) but all my MongoDB entries are stored in UTC format. So if I want to query entries for all of yesterday, I have to overcompensate for the timezone:

```
  tz = 5.hours
  d1 = Date.yesterday.at_midnight + tz
  d2 = d1 + 1.day
  Entry.where(:created_at.gte => d1, :created_at.lt => d2)
```

I'm pretty sure that this is a major hack, but I'm not sure how to fix this correctly?  Should it be on the database end, or in the code. Are there some reading resources that teach how to do this correctly?

Comment: Use the [TZInfo](http://tzinfo.github.io/) gem.  Don't rely on your system's time zone setting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that your Rails application is configured to use UTC (see `config.time_zone` in `config/application.rb`) then you should be able to use `Time.zone...` to build your dates.

I'm in Pacific time, my app is in UTC:

```
> Time.now
=> 2013-09-10 15:14:46 -0700
> Time.zone.now
=> Tue, 10 Sep 2013 22:14:48 UTC +00:00
```

I don't know about Mongoid, but ActiveRecord will do this for you:

```
> Course.where(['created_at < ?', Time.now]).to_sql
=> "SELECT \"courses\".* FROM \"courses\"  WHERE (created_at < '2013-09-10 22:16:27.106841')"
> Course.where(['created_at < ?', Time.zone.now]).to_sql
=> "SELECT \"courses\".* FROM \"courses\"  WHERE (created_at < '2013-09-10 22:17:03.236353')"
```